# Extraer el primer día del mes de una columna de tipo timestamp en pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
0      2017-01-03
1      2017-01-04
2      2017-01-05
3      2017-01-06
4      2017-01-09
          ...    
1245   2021-12-13
1246   2021-12-14
1247   2021-12-15
1248   2021-12-16
1249   2021-12-17
```

Quiero crear una funcion en python para que en el primer dia del mes (que como se puede apreciar no siempre empieza por el día 1) devuelva 'x', caso contrario devuelva 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

te paso una idea:

Suponiendo que tienes un DataFrame con las fechas que indicas:

````
#Haces Split para dividir en columnas

df['fecha']=df['fecha'].astype(str)
fh = df["fecha"].str.split('-', expand=True)
fh.columns = ['Anio', 'Mes','Dia']
df2 = pd.concat([df, fh], axis=1)```


RESULTADO:

    fecha   Anio    Mes Dia
0   2017-01-04  2017    01  04
1   2017-01-05  2017    01  05
2   2017-01-06  2017    01  06
3   2017-01-09  2017    01  09
4   2021-12-13  2021    12  13
... continua

#Agrupas
df3=df2.groupby(df2['Anio'])['Dia'].min()
df3.head()

RESULTADO: (Año y día menor de ese año)

Anio
2017    04
2021    13
Name: Dia, dtype: object

A partir de aquí creo que puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades!! :) espero haberte ayudado!
````

Comment: * Disculpa mis fechas las empecé por 04 para el año 2017 y en tu caso empieza por 03 pero el resultado es el mismo